# How can I send data to client-side after an API call when the caller is in another application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 web apps. One web app acts as a host (lets label as Host). All Web APIs resides here. Then the other web app calls those Web APIs (lets label as Client).

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:
Client calls a Web API using Jquery Ajax in Host and host processes this. After successful process, I want to be able to send some message in the HOST's client-side so I can update some UI.

That's the part I am unsure about. To notify the client-side of the Host so I can do some changes in UI, when the caller is in another app. I can't think of a way to pass some message so I can raise some popup, change some text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to accomplish is this: Client calls a Web API using Jquery Ajax in Host and host processes this. After successful process, I want to be able to send some message in the HOST's client-side so I can update some UI.

To achieve the requirement, you can try to integrate SignalR functionality into Apps.

Clients can connect to hub server, and clients can be added to two different groups, which provide a method for broadcasting messages to specified subsets of connected clients.

For more information about ASP.NET Core SignalR, you can check following docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-3.1#groups-in-signalr